# Errno 13 when installing python package

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, terminal

I'm pretty new to programming and I've just downloaded Ubuntu onto my laptop. 
The problem I'm having is when I try to install the python package tabulate (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) from the terminal it displays an error telling me I don't have permission to do so.

```
    kai@kai-HP-Notebook:~$ pip install tabulate
Downloading/unpacking tabulate
  Downloading tabulate-0.7.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_kai/tabulate/setup.py) egg_info for package tabulate

Installing collected packages: tabulate
  Running setup.py install for tabulate
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tabulate.py'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_kai/tabulate/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-If5xKf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

copying tabulate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

running install_lib

copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/tabulate.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tabulate.py'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_kai/tabulate/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-If5xKf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_kai/tabulate
Storing debug log for failure in /home/kai/.pip/pip.log
```

What I am doing wrong? I'm sure its quite an easy problem to get around.

Comment: Use `sudo pip install tabulate`.

Comment: or `pip install --user tabulate`

Comment: Wow thanks that was even easier than I thought it would be

Comment: Use virtualenv for avoid `sudo` permissions. Ref :https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide.html

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro please add your answer in "Answers" below so there can be history of the correct answer for future generations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by @JRodDynamite: Use

```
sudo pip install tabulate
```

Comment: Don't copy paste from comments !

Comment: Please don't copy from comments.

Comment: then ask the guy that answered you on the comment to put it as answer so he can as well get the +reputation from his answer.

Comment: @hedgehog - It's okay. Let him post it as an answer. Consider this as my welcome gift. Welcome to SO! :)